# Curve fitting R 3D model from 2D model

Tags: r, curve

In a previous question here in stack overflow you have helped find the best model to fit my data in R. In that regard using the `nls` function and the following model

```
f(x) = a/( b1 + b*x + (x*(x-1.877))^n)
```

I have achieved a very good fit.

However, my observed data is not univariate. In other words, my data seems to follow that model for various levels. For instance for a value of `x`:

```
x <- c(1.877,1.898,2.711,4.338,7.592,13.107,21.844)

Z(x,f1(x)) = 5
Z(x,f2(x)) = 20
Z(x,f3(x)) = 40
Z(x,f4(x)) = 60
```

The various f functions have different `a` and `b` parameters, but with the same n.

My question: What is the best way to generate a 3D model (the `Z` function above) of my data? Can I somehow compose the various f functions to generate it? Or is it simpler to take all raw data and try to generate the model from there?

**EDIT:** as suggested I am inserting the dataset:

For 5% of CPU utilization (Z):

```
x1 (SIZE in GB) <- c(1.877,1.898,2.711,4.338,6.507,7.592,8.676,13.107,21.844) 
y1 (#REQUESTS per second) <- c(790,450,125,90,60,45,40,22,22)
```

For 20% of CPU utilization:

```
x2 (SIZE in GB) <- c(1.877,1.898,2.711,4.338,6.507,7.592,8.676,13.107,21.844) 
y2 (#REQUESTS per second) <- c(4600,2600,780,500,180,140,120,77,72)
```

and also for 40% and 60% utilization. I know the 2-dimensional model for each of the CPU utilization level to fit this model

```
f(x) = a/( b1 + b*x + (x*(x-1.877))^n)
```

What I want to do is to come up with a 3D surface that by providing `x` (Size in GB) and `y` (#REQUESTS per second) I could predict the value of CPU utilization (`Z`). In addition, the model should not be bounded by my data range, in other words the maximum of `Z` should tend to infinity (not 100%, I want to use `Z` as a score not a percentage for my algorithm).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you really need fitting functions, or would a 2-dimensional spline fit suffice?  The latter will allow you to generate the 3D surface for plotting, for example; there are several packages which will perform a 2D spline fit.

Comment: I have used fitting functions because first I wanted to see and try to predict the different values of y as I incremented x. Secondly, I thought it would be easier then to infer the 3D model. Knowing hardly anything about splines fitting can I still predict the values for the intermediate levels for instance for Z()=50?

Comment: I don't think I understand what you want to do.  Do you want to fit $Z(x,f_j(x)) = 50$  for all `j` or just for one particular function--and how are you picking those right-hand values?

Comment: Ok so maybe I should try to explain myself better.

I have the following dataset, for 5% of CPU utilization (Z):

x1 (SIZE in GB) <- c(1.877,1.898,2.711,4.338,6.507,7.592,8.676,13.107,21.844)
y1 (#REQUESTS per second) <- c(790,450,125,90,60,45,40,22,22)

for 20% of CPU utilization:

x1 (SIZE in GB) <- c(1.877,1.898,2.711,4.338,6.507,7.592,8.676,13.107,21.844)
y2 (#REQUESTS per second) <- c(4600,2600,780,500,180,140,120,77,72)

and also for 40% and 60% utilization. I know the 2-dimensional model for each of the CPU utilization level to fit this model: f(x)= a/( b1 + b*x + (x*(x-1.877))^n)

Comment: What I want to do is to come up with a 3D surface that by providing x (Size in GB) and y (#REQUESTS per second) I could predict the value of CPU utilization (Z). In addition, the model should not be bounded by my data range, in other words the maximum of Z should tend to infinity (I want to use Z as a score not a percentage for my algorithm)

Comment: You should edit yr question w/ that useful set of sample data in yr comment :-)